# Multi Network module in Hilt Android

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

My app fetches data from two different rout, I want to create network module for both urls, How can I do this using `Hilt` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Provides
LoginAPI provideAPI(gson:Gson, client:OkHttpClient, baseUrlHolder:BaseUrlHolder) {
return Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
                        .client(client)
                        .baseUrl(baseUrlHolder.get())
                        .build().create(LoginAPI.class)
}

@AppScope
@Provides
BaseUrlHolder provideBaseUrlHolder() {
    return BaseUrlHolder("https://www.default.com")
}
```

Then use like

```
App.appComponent.getBaseUrlHolder().set("https://www.changed.com");
this.loginApi = App.appComponent.getLoginApi();
```